# CMYK JPG Images appear inverted in Photoshop after creating PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, photoshop

I'm evaluating iTextSharp (iText) to see if it can handle the workflow we're setting up. We use iTextSharp to create PDFs from images. We have a problem with the PDFs that are based on JPG CMYK images. When opening them in Photoshop they appear inverted, appearing normal in other softwares.

I have found the following thread that sort of explains the problem:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12894/cmyk-jpegs-extracted-from-pdf-appear-inverted

My question is if I can do anything about this when creating the PDF? Is there a setting in iTextSharp that would help me around this problem?

Current code looks like this:

```
iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(sourcePath);

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            using (Document doc = new Document(image))
            {
                using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
                {
                    doc.Open();
                    image.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
                    writer.DirectContent.AddImage(image);
                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Convert your JPGs to another format before adding them to the PDF. If you keep them as JPGs you'll always have the problem as explained in the question you refer to. iTextSharp doesn't change a byte to the JPEGs you add. The JPEGs are OK for the whole world, but not for PhotoShop uses a different interpretation of "ink coverage". If you change your JPGs into PNGs first, your problem may be solved.